# How to foreach multiple SimpleXML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am using Last.fm get event by venue API call. It returns an XML with multiple objects

```
print_r($xml)
```

This is the result

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [events] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
           [event] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                           ....
                        )
                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                           ....
                        )
                    ....
                )
        )
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
     .............
     .............
)
```

I can apply foreach loop like this

```
foreach($xml->events->event as $data) {
    ...
}
```

But it returns only data from first object. How can I get or loop data from other objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call children() function

```
foreach($xml->events->children() as $data) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`events` is an object with one member, `event`. I guess you can do

```
foreach($xml->events->event as $data) {
    ...
}
```

Mind you that again, `$data` will be an object.